# Can't produce tabular content from a webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

After I click on the `See all hours` button located in the upper left corner next to the `Closed now` button on this [webpage](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g60763-d1236281-Reviews-Club_A_Steakhouse-New_York_City_New_York.html), a box containing a schedule appears. I've created a script in Selenium to mimic the steps. However, the results the script produces are haphazard. I wish to get the tabular content from there in the following manner:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')

link = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g60763-d1236281-Reviews-Club_A_Steakhouse-New_York_City_New_York.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.get(link)
hours = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@data-automation='top-info-hours']//span[contains(.,' See all hours')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",hours)
for elem in WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[./span[.='Hours']]/following::div/div"))):
    print(elem.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Current output:

```
Sun5:00 PM - 11:00 PM
Sun
5:00 PM - 11:00 PM
5:00 PM - 11:00 PM
Tue5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Tue
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Wed5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Wed
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Thu5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Thu
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Fri5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Fri
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Sat5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Sat
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
```

Expected output:

```
Sun 5:00 PM - 11:00 PM
Tue 5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Wed 5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Thu 5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Fri 5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
Sat 5:00 PM - 10:00 PM
```

Note: Sticking with selenium is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of getting that data in tabular format(EDIT: improved Open Hours detection for restaurants Opened Now):

```
import pandas as pd
[...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
opening_hours_list = []
driver.get(link)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    print('accepted cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')
hours = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),' See all hours')] | //span[contains(text(),' Open now')]")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",hours)
for elem in WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Hours']/following::div/div"))):
    if elem.get_attribute('textContent')[0].isdigit() or len(elem.get_attribute('textContent')) < 4:

        opening_hours_list.append(elem.get_attribute('textContent').replace(' ', '').strip())


final_list = [tuple(opening_hours_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(opening_hours_list), 3)]
df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['day', 'opening_hours', 'redundant'])
df = df.drop('redundant', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    day     opening_hours
0   Sun     5:00 PM-11:00 PM
1   Tue     5:00 PM-10:00 PM
2   Wed     5:00 PM-10:00 PM
3   Thu     5:00 PM-10:00 PM
4   Fri     5:00 PM-10:00 PM
5   Sat     5:00 PM-10:00 PM
```

Here is [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) and respectively [Pandas'](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/), just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've solved this by tweaking the last two lines of the above script:

```
for elem in WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[./span[.='Hours']]/following::div/div[./div[text()]]"))):
    print(elem.text.replace("\n"," "))
```